# Understanding a security error with RC4 using the same key to encrypt on the client/server sides

Tags: rc4

This apparently was a bug with WhatsApp a while ago. I am endeavoring to recreate it and understand it.

The bug had to do with the fact that the same key was used to encrypt plaintext on both the client and server sides. However, `(A ^ X) ^ (B ^ X) = A ^ B ; ^ is the bitwise XOR function`. In other words, if if there are two messages encrypted with the same RC4 key, the key stream cancels out.

To illustrate this with an example: we have a simulator which creates a bunch of messages for both the server and client side. For the sake of simplicity, assume that all the messages are 128 bytes long (i.e. they are always padded to ensure they are that length) so that we do not have to guess where messages start and end.

An example message from the client side is: `LOGIN JOHN foo //padding`

An example message from the server side is: `INVALID PASSWORD //padding`

I don't know either of these messages.

Say that with a bit of traffic sniffing, I've come into the possession of two files, `ServerSideEncrypted.dat` and `ClientSideEncrypted.dat`.

Reading the first byte from `ServerSideEncrypted.dat` I discover that `Byte1SS_encrypt = 01111100` and reading the first byte from `ClientSideEncrypted.dat` I discover that `Byte1CS_encrypt = 01111001`. Now, `01111100 ^ 01111001 = 00000101`.

To ensure that this checks out, assuming that I *did* know the first letters of each of the messages from the client and server sides, I would have `Byte1CS_plain (the letter L) = 76 (in ascii) = 01001100` and `Byte1SS_plain (the letter I) = 73 (in ascii) = 01001001`. `01001100 ^ 01001001 = 00000101`. So indeed, the XOR of the two encrypted bytes is equivalent to the XOR of the two plaintext bytes.

At this point is where I become stuck. I know the following things:

```
Byte1CS_plain ^ Byte1SS_plain = Byte1CS_encrypt ^ Byte1SS_encrypt = 00000101
Byte1CS_encrypt = 01111001
Byte1SS_encrypt = 01111100
```

However, this still leaves me with 2 unknowns. How do I proceed with this information to decipher the messages? How do I figure out that `Byte1CS_plain = 01001100` and `Byte1SS_plain = 01001001`?

Comment: Could you post a link to the bug documentation that you are working on?

Comment: Continue the with next blocks with the same procedure and extract the current key bits. This is a common way to attack such schemes that you have only key bits as extracted plaintext Hopefully, you will get enough key stream to find the key by applying an attack with the known key-stream bits.